# jest: mock const is not defines

Tags: mocking, jestjs

I am trying to mock constant from dependency module in jest:

```
const MOCK_CONTEXT = {
  eventName: 'eventName'
}

jest.mock('@actions/github/lib/github', function () {
  return {
    context: MOCK_CONTEXT
  }
})
```

But I get an error

> ReferenceError: CONTEXT_MOCK is not defined

What is the problem here, how can it even happen?

If I do not refer to an already existent constant, everything is ok.
This code also works fine:

```
const MOCK_INPUT = {
  GITHUB_TOKEN: 'GITHUB_TOKEN'
}
jest.mock('../src/action-inputs', () => ({ getInputs: () => MOCK_INPUT }))
```

Is there any workaround to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

jest.mock recieves a factory function as a second argument. It is a High order function, which should return a function, which returns a mocked value.

So your code should look like:

```
jest.mock('@actions/github/lib/github', function () {
  return () => ({
    context: MOCK_CONTEXT
  });
})
```

And import path in the tested file should be exactly `@actions/github/lib/github`.

Comment: Here is the docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmockdocsenjest-objectjestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter